# How to fit big table automatically?

Tags: tables

I have this table:

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ l | l | l | l}
    \hline
    Tipus & Pot incloure com a membres: & Permisos & Es pot convertir a: \\ \hline
    Universal & Comptes de qualsevol domini del bosc en el qual resideix aquest grup universal\\Els grups globals de qualsevol domini del bosc en el qual resideix aquest grup universal\\Els grups universals de qualsevol domini del bosc en el qual resideix aquest grup universal & Qualsevol domini o bosc & Domini local\\Global (sempre que no hi hagi altres grups universals com a membres) \\ \hline
    Global & Comptes en el mateix domini que el grup global dels pares\\Els grups globals del mateix domini que el grup global dels pares & Els permisos de membre es poden assignar en qualsevol domini & Universal (sempre que no sigui un membre d'altres grups globals) \\ \hline
    Domini local & Comptes de qualsevol domini\\Grups globals de qualsevol domini\\Grups universals de qualsevol domini\\Grups locals de domini, però només des del mateix domini que el grup local de domini principal & Els permisos dels membres es poden assignar només dins del mateix domini que el grup local de domini principal & Universal (sempre que no hi hagi altres grups locals de domini com a membres)\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
}
```

And I don't get the result I want: 
[image]

I did a research here at stackexchange first but I'm too new for this at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: Please paste a copy & pasteable piece of code (this will make helping you a lot easier).

Also, your screenshot doesn't make clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Add `\noindent` before the `\resizebox` makes it fit. Not very readable though. You could consider reorganinzing (ie use `p{}` column types) the table or rotating it.

Comment: @Euryris Like this?: http://paste.debian.net/plain/95917

Comment: @SouL I meant something including the \documentclass, \begin{document}, \end{document} and/or other packages you might need to get what you pasted to work.

Comment: do you really want to use `l` entries which are single line entries (like `\mbox`) if you use `p{3cm}` the cells would linebreak and you could avoid scaling (scaling tables is evil:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or if you are looking for preserving font size this option will be more suitable

```
\begin{tabular}{ l | l | l | l}
    \hline
    Tipus & Pot incloure com a membres: & Permisos & Es pot convertir a: \\ \hline
    Universal & \parbox[c]{0.25\columnwidth}{Comptes de qualsevol domini del bosc  en el qual resideix aquest grup universal\\ Els grups globals de qualsevol domini del bosc en el qual resideix aquest grup universal\\ Els grups universals de qualsevol domini del bosc en el qual resideix aquest grup universal} & Qualsevol domini o bosc & \parbox[c]{0.25\columnwidth}{Domini local Global (sempre que no hi hagi altres grups universals com a membres)} \\ \hline
    Global & \parbox[c]{0.25\columnwidth}{ Comptes en el mateix domini que el grup global dels pares\\ Els grups globals del mateix domini que el grup global dels pares} & \parbox[c]{0.25\columnwidth}{ Els permisos de membre es poden assignar en qualsevol domini }& \parbox[c]{0.25\columnwidth}{Universal (sempre que no sigui un membre d'altres grups globals) }\\ \hline
    Domini local & \parbox[c]{0.25\columnwidth}{Comptes de qualsevol domini\\ Grups globals de qualsevol domini\\ Grups universals de qualsevol domini\\ Grups locals de domini, però només des del mateix domini que el grup local de domini principal }& \parbox[c]{0.25\columnwidth}{ Els permisos dels membres es poden assignar només dins del mateix domini que el grup local de domini principal} & \parbox[c]{0.25\columnwidth}{Universal (sempre que no hi hagi altres grups locals de domini com a membres)}\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
```

the command \parbox[c]{0.25\columnwidth}{} sets that table's column to a width that is a quarter of your document textwidth and allows text inside to breakline automatic like a minipage (see image) [image]

Comment: Ho-ho! You did it! Thank you very much! Copying your code makes it automatic too :P

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what's wrong with your pdf output what are  you really trying to do? but try this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htdp]
\begin{center}
\resizebox{0.5\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{ l | l | l | l}
    \hline
    Tipus & Pot incloure com a membres: & Permisos & Es pot convertir a: \\ \hline
    Universal & Comptes de qualsevol domini del bosc en el qual resideix aquest grup universal\\Els grups globals de qualsevol domini del bosc en el qual resideix aquest grup universal\\Els grups universals de qualsevol domini del bosc en el qual resideix aquest grup universal & Qualsevol domini o bosc & Domini local\\Global (sempre que no hi hagi altres grups universals com a membres) \\ \hline
    Global & Comptes en el mateix domini que el grup global dels pares\\Els grups globals del mateix domini que el grup global dels pares & Els permisos de membre es poden assignar en qualsevol domini & Universal (sempre que no sigui un membre d'altres grups globals) \\ \hline
    Domini local & Comptes de qualsevol domini\\Grups globals de qualsevol domini\\Grups universals de qualsevol domini\\Grups locals de domini, però només des del mateix domini que el grup local de domini principal & Els permisos dels membres es poden assignar només dins del mateix domini que el grup local de domini principal & Universal (sempre que no hi hagi altres grups locals de domini com a membres)\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
} 
\caption{default}
\label{default}
\end{center}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

the option 0.5 before \columnwidth allows you to specify the width of the table to half the textwidth of your doc, it can be whatever you want between 0(null) and 1 (max)